# SQL Limit + count

Tags: mysql, count, limit, unique

I'm tracking all the visitors of my site using this table:

[Visitors table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61mws.png)

In my admin panel, I have an overview of which countries visited my site, where they came from, ..., but because over 20+ different countries have visited my site already, the chart looks like this:

[Messed up chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkx2c.png)

To solve this, I want to select the top 5 countries, but I have no clue on how to do this.

I've tried using LIMIT & COUNT but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you shoule use order by.
for exam:select * from visitors order by day limit 5;
hope this will help you